# Updating Google Analytics Audience returns 500 from Management API (Python)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to update a remarketing audience segment on google analytics 
from

```
sessions::condition::ga:pagePath=@/cart
```

to (match regex)

```
sessions::condition::ga:pagePath=~/cart
```

But I keep getting 500 response from the management API, interestingly also I am unable to update via the UI either, the UI just keeps on saying 'Resource is not available. Please try again later.

I don't have really anywhere else to turn to as the developer forum has been closed off and the issue tracker doesn't allow me to create any issues - google analytics just says raise it on stackoverflow.

I have not done much to combat this as the 500 error doesn't really tell me much.

I have double checked the request I am sending and know this to be working as I have other audiences being updated in the same way, so kind of leaning towards some kind of data error.

This is the python code that sends the request

```
response = analytics_client.management().remarketingAudience().update(
                            accountId=analytics_id,
                            webPropertyId=property_id,
                            remarketingAudienceId=existing_audience['id'],
                            body={
                                'name': existing_audience['name'],
                                'linkedViews': existing_audience['linkedViews'],
                                'linkedAdAccounts': existing_audience['linkedAdAccounts'],
                                'audienceType': existing_audience['audienceType'],
                                'audienceDefinition': {
                                    'includeConditions': {
                                        'isSmartList': False,
                                        'daysToLookBack': 7,
                                        'membershipDurationDays': days,
                                        'segment': expected_segment
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ).execute()
```

I expect it to just update the audience definition with the new segment I am supplying.

The response is:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 500 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/<account_id>/webproperties/<property_id>/remarketingAudiences/<audience id>=json returned "There was an internal error.">
```